# Python: Replace string in a txt file but not on every occurrence

Tags: python

I am really new to python and I need to change new artikel Ids to the old ones. The Ids are mapped inside a dict. The file I need to edit is a normal txt where every column is sperated by Tabs. The problem is not replacing the values rather then only replacing the ouccurances in the desired column which is set by pos.

I really would appreciate some help.

```
def replaceArtCol(filename, pos):
    with open(filename) as input_file, open('test.txt','w') as output_file:
        for each_line in input_file:
            val = each_line.split("\t")[pos]
            for row in artikel_ID:
                if each_line[pos] == pos
                    line = each_line.replace(val, artikel_ID[val])
            output_file.write(line)`
```

This Code just replaces any occurance of the string in the text file.

Comment: Welcome, solesins! Your code is not so easy to understand. Can you explain how/where you define artikel_ID? It seems like what you need to do is test if each_line.split("\t")[pos] is equal to the to-replace value; replace it if so and write the line to the output file (re-placing the tabs). Not sure what the for loop is doing; don't think you need it if I read your question right.

Comment: @Solesins You would receive higher quality answers, if you provided an example of the text file you are trying to read and your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supposed your ID mapping dict looks like `ID_mapping = {'old_id': 'new_id'}`, I think your code is not far from working correctly. A modified version could look like

```py
with open(filename) as input_file, open('test.txt','w') as output_file:
    for each_line in input_file:
        line = each_line.split("\t")
        if line[pos] in ID_mapping.keys():
            line[pos] = ID_mapping[line[pos]]
        line = '\t'.join(line)
        output_file.write(line)
```

if you're not working in `pandas` anyway, this can save a lot of overhead.

Comment: you are right I had allready a very similar approache. It works but somehow only the last line of the file gets saved to the txt instead of everyone.

Comment: @Solesins: hm, if I run the code I posted above with a dummy file input, it works fine.

Comment: I printed the line= '\t'.join(line) to the console and everything was shown. But in the test.txt only the last line exists.

Comment: maybe an indentation problem? did you try it with copy-pasing my code?

Comment: I accidently indented the output_file.write(lines) Thanks for helping me out. Have a greate Day!

Answer (score 0):

if your data is tab separated then you must load this data into dataframe.. this way you can have columns and rows structure.. what you are sdoing right now will not allow you to do what you want to do without some complex and buggy logic. you may try these steps

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("dummy.txt", sep="\t", encoding="latin-1")
df['desired_column_name'] = df['desired_column_name'].replace({"value_to_be_changed": "newvalue"})
print(df.head())
```

Comment: @Altas Bravoos it does not change any value when I am running it. Also I do not recive any kind of error message.

Comment: if you still encounter some problem then kindly send me the print output

Comment: @Altas Bravoos the output shows a changed artikel id but how can I save it to the file now? Thank you so much for taking time to help me

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html